# "Help/let/make you get over nervousness" - which one is recommended?

Tags: word-choice

Which verb would you recommend to use?

> Our course will help you get over nervousness.
>
> Our course will let you get over nervousness.
>
> Our course will make you get over nervousness.

Comment: It's really just a stylistic choice, but for what it's worth, most such "product endorsement" claims go for ***can help***, because it allows a bit of "wiggle room" if an unhappy customer complains that it didn't actually help *him*. Also note that *get over* (do you mean ***gain control** [of current nervousness]* or ***become reconciled to** [past nervousness]*?) is a bit "slangy". You might consider alternatives such as ***control, master***.

Answer (score 1):

The three phrases have different meanings, so much depends on what you want to say:

> Our course will *help you* ...

If you choose to do X, our course will assist you in achieving X

> Our course will *let you* ...

If you have trouble doing X, our course will help you overcome this trouble.

> Our course will *make you*

Whether or not you have strong feelings about X, our course will push you to achieve X.

Context is important to decide which to use.  For example, a self-help speaker might say:

> My course will **make you** a master at getting what you want!

The speaker knows that his audience wants this, but they also respond well to "forceful", aggressive statements. On the other hand, "let you", and "help you" are gentle and non-threatening, and may be appropriate for people who would otherwise resist being told what to do:

> If you have a drinking problem, our course will **help you / let you** regain control of your life.

[Edit]  The question has been edited, but these answers should still apply